# Show that $(Tx,Ty)=0$ if $(x,y)=0$ implies that $T$ is a multiple of a unitary map

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, unitary-matrices

> Let $V$ be a complex inner product space and $T$ be a linear map on
>   $V$ such that $(Tx,Ty)=0$ if $(x,y)=0$. Show that $T=kU$, where $U$ is
>   a unitary map on $V$.

Unfortunately I don`t even know how to approach this problem. I thought about the following:

- show directly that $T^*T=k^2I$
- by the polar decomposition $T=UN$, where $N$ is some non-negative matrix, so one may try to show that $N=I$ in that case
- show that $T$ is an injective (one-to-one) isometry, then it`s unitary

What should I do in this problem? Any hints or solutions are welcomed.

Comment: Is $V$ finite dimensional?

Comment: @Reveillark, it isn`t mentioned in the statement of the problem.

Comment: Is $V$ complete? Your approach suggests that you are asuming completeness.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, no additional assumptions -- I provided complete statement of the problem. I just don`t know how to do it in any case, so I wrote my attempts, but of course they can be meaningless.

Comment: Let $e_1,e_2,\ldots$ be an orthogonal basis of $V$. We have $0=(e_i,e_j)=(Te_i,Te_j)=(e_i,T^*Te_j)=0$ for all $i\neq j$. From this it follows that $T^*T=\lambda_i e_i$ for some $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{C}$.  Now it is not hard to see that the $\lambda_i$'s have the same module, and are in fact real.

Comment: @jijijojo Do inner product spaces have complete orthonormal bases? OP doesn't want to assume completeness. For Hilbert spaces this question is easy and it has been answered earlier on this site.